# Como criar uma classe onde conecte no Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, mobile, firestore

Estou tentando criar um classe onde nela vou conecta no Firestore do Firebase, e depois vou pegar esta classe e instanciar ela onde for necessário, eu fiz estar essa parte do código porém não sei mais o que fazer.

Classe que conecta no firebase

public class CloudFirestore {

```
FirebaseFirestore connection;

public CloudFirestore(FirebaseFirestore connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

public FirebaseFirestore getConnection() {
    return connection;
}

public void setConnection(FirebaseFirestore connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}
```

---

Classe que instancio a minha conexao e adiciono um registro no firebase.

CloudFirestore cloudFirestore = new CloudFirestore();

```
    Map<String, Object> report = new HashMap<>();
    report.put("name", this.editTextName);
    report.put("dateWorked", this.editDateWorked);
    report.put("timeInput", this.editTimeInput);
    report.put("timeExit", this.editTimeExit);
    report.put("goodParts", this.editNumberGoodParts);
    report.put("badParts", this.editNumberBadParts);
    report.put("workedPlace", this.editTextWorkedPlace);
    report.put("mails", this.editTextMails);

    if (report != null) {

        cloudFirestore.setConnection().collection("reports")
                .add(report)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

A primeira vista, só sinto falta do construtor para inicializar a classe...

Algo do tipo:

`public CloudFirestore () {
   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}`

A classe está dando algum erro? Fica difícil ajudar sem saber o problema...